# grails test-app Only classes and closures can be used for attribute 'value' in @grails.test.mixin.TestFor

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I'm starting with testing for Grails (version 2.2.4).

When I run: **grails test-app**

I got:

```
Error Compilation error compiling [unit] tests: startup failed:
```

Log:

```
/myproject/test/unit/app/AutocompleteServiceTests.groovy: 11: Only classes and closures can be used for attribute 'value' in @grails.test.mixin.TestFor
 @ line 11, column 10.
  @TestFor(AutocompleteService)

/myproject/test/unit/app/CoachControllerTests.groovy: 11: Only classes and closures can be used for attribute 'value' in @grails.test.mixin.TestFor
 @ line 11, column 10.
  @TestFor(CoachController)
```

I have 21 errors, one per each ***Test.groovy** file.

I tried: **grails clean** before, but I have the same error.

The Test files was created autmatically by Grails when I create new Domain, Controller or Service.

Comment: I get the same error in 2.3.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem.

I have unit test for models or controllers that was deleted, renamed or changed package.

I deleted all the unit test files and I created each one manually and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was running my tests in interactive mode using -clean and got the same error

`grails> test-app -clean -echoOut`

It was being caused by the `-clean` flag. Took that out and things work fine.

Running Grails 2.3.8 on windows 7